# Identify abbreviations in a string column

Tags: python, pandas, regex, nlp, abbreviation

Given the following data frame for instance (mind you the original data for this column is a dtype('0'))

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_description': ["CUTLERY HVY DUTY FORKS", "XYZ DISP LQD SOAP", "ABCD FOOD STRG CNTNR"]})
```

How can I effectively identify and separate the abbreviations and produce a result like

```
product_description            abbreviations
0  CUTLERY HVY DUTY FORKS        [HVY]

1  XYZ DISP LQD SOAP             [XYZ,DISP,LQD]

2  ABCD FOOD STRG CNTNR          [ABCD,STRG,CNTNR]
```

So i convert the abbreviations into full words.

i have tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'product_description': ["CUTLERY HVY DUTY FORKS", "XYZ DISP LQD SOAP", "ABCD FOOD STRG CNTNR"]})

def extract_abbreviations(description):
    abbreviation_pattern = r'\b[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])'  # Updated regular expression pattern to match abbreviations
    abbreviations = re.findall(abbreviation_pattern, description)
    return abbreviations

df['abbreviations'] = df['product_description'].apply(extract_abbreviations)
print(df)
```

but this is what i get :

```
product_description            abbreviations
0  CUTLERY HVY DUTY FORKS        [CUTLERY,HVY,DUTY,FORKS]

1  XYZ DISP LQD SOAP             [XYZ,DISP,LQD,SOAP]

2  ABCD FOOD STRG CNTNR          [ABCD,FOOD,STRG,CNTNR]
```

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: what are you really trying to do here? are you trying to automatically determine that `"SOAP"` is not an abbreviation or do you have a collection of words or non-words? for example, [LOX might be brined salmon or an abbreviation for liquid oxygen](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=33048945)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to automatically determine that SOAP, CUTLERY, and FOOD are not abbreviations because I have a column of 30,000 different items in this format. It would be too tasking to do manually. Eventually, my goal is to get a column of abbreviations per item description.@ti7

Comment: I suggest relying on a list of known words (ie, a standard dictionary, for instance the scrabble's dictionary) and a list of known abbreviations. Then consider the three cases: A) the word is in the standard dictionary and not in the list of abbreviations; B) the word is in the list of abbreviations and not in the standard dictionary; C) The word is in both the dictionary and the list of abbreviations

Comment: ah, I mean what is your overall goal? why get the abbreviations? to eventually map them into their expanded values? what is eventually consuming this result? you might have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The end goal is to have item descriptions in full understandable words, so `CUTLERY HVY DUTY FORKS` would be `CUTLERY HEAVY DUTY FORKS`. @ti7

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a list of abb `['XYZ', 'DISP', 'LQD', 'ABCD', 'STRG', 'CNTNR', 'HVY', 'SOAP']`
You should be able the apply the below logic to obtain the desired result

```
abb=['XYZ', 'DISP', 'LQD', 'ABCD', 'STRG', 'CNTNR', 'HVY', 'SOAP']
def return_abb(row):
    return list(set(row.split(" ")) & set(abb))
df['abbreviations']=df['product_description'].apply(return_abb)
```

Comment: I don't have a list of all the abbreviations. The column i am working with has 30,000 different items and extracting that manually would be a lot of work. I need to automatically detect the abbreviations

Comment: casually, does making a single `set()` of every term cut 'em down to a manageable number such that they could be manually inspected?

Comment: This is what i get with `set()`, `'CUTLERY HVY DUTY FORKS','XYZ DISP LQD SOAP','ABCD FOOD STRG CNTNR'`

Comment: ah, I mean `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(row.split() for row in df["product_description"]))` (watch out, this might be very inefficient for a large dataframe)